# How to return only specified fields from serializerMethodField using DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

It will return nested array like { project_name:test, site_id:[[1],[2]],site_name:[[test1],[test2]] },but I would like to return like this {{sitename:test1, siteid:1},{sitename:test2, siteid:2}}

```
class ProjectSite(models.Model):
    site_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,name='project_site_name')
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, 
    related_name="projectid")
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
class ProjectSiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectSite
        fields = '__all__'
class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    site_ids = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    site_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)
    
    ...

    def get_site_ids(self, obj):
        return list(obj.projectid.values_list('id').distinct())
    def get_site_name(self, obj):
        return list(obj.projectid.values_list('site_name').distinct())
```

Comment: Could you add the serializer for the `ProjectSite` model here?

Comment: The current serializer is for the `Project` model, right?

Comment: No, ProjectSite model

Comment: U asked me to add ProjectSite Serializer right?

Comment: No, this serializer must be of the `Project` model. Because `obj` uses the `projectid` attribute.

Comment: Why do you use `Serializer` separately from the ProjectSerializer? I thought the `Serializer` was the one for the `Project` model.

Comment: I just created separate serializer for all models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the `ProjectSerializer`.

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    projectid = ProjectSiteSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('project_id', 'project_name', 'projectid',)
```